# Is this potential loop a problem in my database ERD?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I am creating an ERD for what will eventually be a fairly simple (I think) CRM database. I know enough about database design that I am aware loops can be problematic. However, I don't know enough to be certain when and if they will be problematic. I have searched SO and have found similar questions, but I am having difficulty applying those answers to my specific question. Here's my ERD:

[image: My ERD]

The tables in the ERD above are not the only tables in the DB, but they are the relevant ones. Just know that there is another table that is basically "Prospects" that together with the "Salesperson" defines the "Lead." (Not every prospect converts to a lead.) Despite my naming convention, territories are not geographical; they are fully properties of the salesperson and not properties of the lead (as they might be if they were geographical). Each salesperson optionally has zero to many "territories," but each of these territories are proprietary and not shared with any other salesperson. Each territory potentially "contains" zero to many leads, but each lead can only be in zero or one territory.

To wrap everything together, if a lead does have a territory, it must exist in the territories table, and that territory is owned by one and only one salesperson.

As of now, I do not currently have the relationship proposed by the items in red (but the Territory field is and must be in the Leads table). What would be the possible dangers in adding this relationship? It seems incomplete without it considering that Leads.Territory must also be in Territories.

Also, would a possible solution be to create a foreign key constraint on a join? Like for instance, something like "Territory REFERENCES (Salespeople JOIN Territories)...."

Thanks in advance for your patience with me. I'm new to this.

Comment: After further study and reflection, it appears that my relationship loop is okay due to the fact that there are no **redundant** relationships being expressed. However, I will wait to answer my own question to see if the community has anything of value to add. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest that ERD is adding an issue (loops) that is not an issue in SQL schemas.